# Probability and Counting: Deck of Cards

Tags: probability, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

8 cards are drawn from a well-shuffled deck of 52. Find the probability that the 8 cards contain 4 of a kind (any kind, including the possibility of 4 of two kinds).

My thoughts: To make a 4 of a kind, you choose one rank out of 13: ${{13}\choose{1}}$ Then, out of 4 suits you choose 4 cards: ${{4}\choose{4}}$. Now, for there are ${{48}\choose{4}}$ to choose the last 4 cards. Multiply those together and now you divide by the total number of ways of choosing 8 cards out of 52: ${{52}\choose{8}}$. Apparently you have to subtract ${{13}\choose{2}}$ in the numerator to account for duplicates but I don't really understand this last part.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You're over counting because  the second set of 4 cards can contain 4 of a kind. For instance, you're counting both AAAAKKKK and KKKKAAAA.

Comment: @FullofDill That makes sense, thanks. So what's the intuitive understanding of why you subtract ${{13}\choose{2}}$? There are ${{13}\choose{2}}$ ways of selecting two cards from a set of 13. How does that help?

Comment: It's similar to why you used ${13 \choose 1}$ to choose one suit. ${13 \choose 2}$ gives you all the possible hands where you have four of a kind twice. This is equal to the number of ways you can choose 2 suits because there are no other cards to choose afterwards. Right now you're counting each of these two times, so you have $2 {13 \choose 2}$. Subtracting ${13 \choose 2}$ once removes the duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A_i$ be the event where we have four cards of value $i$ then
$$p(A_i)=\frac{1\cdot{52-4\choose{4}}}{{52\choose{8}}}=\frac{{48\choose{4}}}{{52\choose{8}}}.$$
Moreover, for $i\not=j$,
$$p(A_i\cap A_j)=\frac{1}{{52\choose{8}}}$$
and the probability involving intersections of three or more distinct events is zero.
Then by the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle#In_probability),
\begin{align*}
P(\bigcup_{i=1}^{13} A_i)&=
\sum_{i=1}^{13} p(A_i)-\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq 13} p(A_i\cap A_j)+0\\
&=13\cdot \frac{{48\choose{4}}}{{52\choose{8}}}-{13\choose{2}}\cdot\frac{1}{{52\choose{8}}}=\frac{13{48\choose{4}}-{13\choose{2}}}{{52\choose{8}}}.
\end{align*}
So the subtraction is due to the fact that we are over counting the elements in the intersections $A_i\cap A_j$.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that inclusion-exclusion would have in other problems also had terms involving intersections of three or more of the events and the reason why they don't appear in this particular problem.

Comment: @JMoravitz Yes, you are right. I edited my answer with a brief comment.